# How to make a field unique in Ninja Forms 3.1?

Tags: wordpress, ninja-forms

I have an event registration form in my ninja forms WordPress installation. I want to have the email field as unique so that a person who's registered with an email address can't register again with the same email address.

Answer (score 0):

As of version 3.1.7 you can select a field to be validated as unique under the Advanced tab of your form (choose Restrictions)

Docs: [https://ninjaforms.com/docs/unique-field-validation/](http://As%20of%20version%203.1.7%20you%20can%20select%20a%20field%20to%20be%20validated%20as%20unique%20under%20the%20Advanced%20tab%20of%20your%20form%20(choose%20Restrictions)%20%20Docs:%20https://ninjaforms.com/docs/unique-field-validation/)